# RVM, ruby 2.4.1 bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, curl, rvm

I'm trying to start a Ruby on Rails project. I'm reading step-by-step guide created by advanced programmer. I failed at the start. I downloaded RVM with command:

> gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys
>   409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC 0E3
>   7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

Then i used:

> curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

And then I tried to use:

> curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails

And here's what happend:

> $ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
>
> Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.3.tar.gz
>   Downloading
>   https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.3/1.29.3.tar.gz.asc
>   gpg: Signature made Sun Sep 10 22:59:21 2017 CEST gpg:
>   using RSA key E206C29FBF04FF17 gpg: Good signature from "Michal Papis
>   (RVM signing) " [unknown] gpg:                 aka
>   "Michal Papis " [unknown] gpg:
>   aka "[jpeg image of size 5015]" [unknown] gpg: WARNING: This key is
>   not certified with a trusted signature! gpg:          There is no
>   indication that the signature belongs to the owner. Primary key
>   fingerprint: 409B 6B17 96C2 7546 2A17  0311 3804 BB82 D39D C0E3
>        Subkey fingerprint: 62C9 E5F4 DA30 0D94 AC36  166B E206 C29F BF04 FF17 GPG verified '/usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.3.tgz'
>
> Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/ Upgrade of RVM in
>   /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.
>
> Upgrade Notes:
>
> - No new notes to display.
>
> Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.3 (latest) (c) 2009-2017 Michal Papis,
>   Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin
>
> Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time. No binary
>   rubies available for: kali/kali-rolling/x86_64/ruby-2.4.1. Continuing
>   with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information
>   on binary rubies. Checking requirements for kali. Installing
>   requirements for kali. Updating system. Installing required packages:
>   zlib1g-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, autoconf, libgdbm-dev,
>   libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, bison, pkg-config,
>   libreadline6-dev, libssl-dev...... Error running
>   'requirements_debian_libs_install zlib1g-dev libyaml-dev
>   libsqlite3-dev autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool
>   bison pkg-config libreadline6-dev libssl-dev', please read
>   /usr/local/rvm/log/1510333806_ruby-2.4.1/package_install_zlib1g-dev_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_autoconf_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_bison_pkg-config_libreadline6-dev_libssl-dev.log Requirements installation failed with status: 100.

Later when i try to get some gems with:

> bundle install --path vendor/bundle

It shows error about sqlite3.

Comment: And what the log mentioned above says?

Comment: Also why are you installing rails on a `kali` build? (And why are you using `kali` if Linux seems relatively new to you?)

Comment: It's simply because the tutorial works on Kali and thanks to that I know every tool I need will or should be available. I'm not that new with the whole Linux thing, I know the basics.

Comment: I don't know Kali, but it has a reputation [for not being beginner-friendly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). I wonder if it's worth just using Ubuntu instead? Rails should be dead easy to set up on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just get Ubuntu and reinstall the whole system since I can't even install missing libraries, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these command to install missing libraries

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
```

And then try to follow the tutorial.

You can also follow [this awesome tutorial from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install Ruby on rails with Rbenv in case you cannot set up rails with RVM.